# How to increase Fetch API speed in AWS environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, amazon-s3, fetch-api

I am sending data from JS file to controller using fetch API. In that, I am sending my model data. When I tried to run my code on my local PC, it is working smoothly but when I deployed my project on AWS and run the project, the same code is taking time.

[AWS deployed timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TpjN.jpg)

As you can see, the fetch API for ReqFormData in AWS is taking 1.5 min.

[Locally deployed timing (Visual studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQlNM.jpg)

As you can see, the fetch API for ReqFormData in Local is taking 2.99 sec

I have checked the size of data model that I am sending to controller from JS is same. I don't know why performance decreases in AWS. Is there any way to increase fetch speed?

Comment: You added same picture to your question twice. But in any case - it is infrastructure problem not programming

Comment: @BoppityBop I have corrected the images and I checked the infrastructure but I did not find any issue

Comment: Please share a [mcve].